# 2003 Opel Agila is making a funny ticking noise on starting

Tags: noise, idle, cold-start

My 2003 Opel Agila 1.2 is making a very loud ticking noise when I start it up, and it doesn't sound right. It only ticks when idling and when I rev it, the ticking noise goes away. The car runs completely fine, but the noise is really annoying and I'm worried that it is something bad.

I had an oil change in December, and I have no warning lights. Also sometimes when I start the car up and the car revs itself up to about 1.2k at idle to warm the O2 sensors, the car judders and shakes, and the ticking noise is really bad. However when I rev it all of this goes away again, but this only happens about once a month.

[I have a recording of the sound here.](https://clyp.it/3m0wm11q) Sorry about the bumping around, I did it with my phone...

The recording is from inside the engine compartment, and you can hear the ticking noise.

Can anyone tell me if this noise is bad? Can I fix it?

---

MORE INFO: My engine is chain driven. There is no timing belt, there is a timing chain.

It's recently started doing it. I've done about 6000 miles since the oil change.

Comment: did it do that before the oil change?

Comment: Do you know when the timing belt has been changed last time? It sounds like a timing belt to me, and a tensioner pulley. If you can't have a look at it, make sure you find someone to look at your belt as soon as you can.

Comment: @ArtursBolsunovskis My engine is chain driven. There is no timing belt, there is a timing chain.

Comment: One cause of a ticking sound is a hydraulic lifter that isn't fully "pumped up" that leaves a bit of slop in the valve train that turns into a tapping or clicking noise. You might try holding a screwdriver the valve cover and listening with an ear on the other end to see if the noise is coming from the valve train. Does the noise ever go away?

Comment: The very top (usually) part of the engine, It usually has the oil fill in it.

Comment: @dlu, so do I just stick a Flathead on top of the valve cover (googled it!)? And then stick my ear in and listen?

Comment: Exactly! The screwdriver will act like a stethoscope and help you isolate the source of the noise. It will also make you bend over the engine, so be careful of long hair, jewelry, loose clothes, anything that could get caught in moving parts – that is usually very unpleasant. Don't forget that the fans are usually thermostatically controlled and may start at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give that a go tomorrow. What should I listen for? Just the ticking?

Comment: It does sound like lifter tick from the audio clip. Does the ticking sound occur only after the vehicle has been left unused for an extended period of time?  That would correlate with a lifter that has lost some oil over time.  With the screwdriver test suggested by @dlu you're looking to confirm that the ticking is chiming from the top end (valve cover). Also, an ageing hydraulic chain tensioner can generate a fair amount of ruckus for the same reason - inability to stay filled with oil.

Comment: What you're listening for are clues that it really is a lifter. It will probably be just one (certainly not all of them) so you might be able to hear the sound more distantly at one point in on the valve cover – and, assuming it is a lifter, you'll hear it more clearly through the screwdriver. If @Zaid is right about the chain tensioner, then you'll hear it most clearly at one end of the valve cover – the one with the chain if you can tell which is which. You may also be able to follow it down the block.

Comment: very interesting :D My Vauxhall (Opel) 1999 Corsa B had a belt. Anyway, yea, it sounds not very healthy and at this point we should figure out how old is your chain and engine (mileage). I would be curious to stick my nose under the cam cover (valve cover) and check everything in there, but before that I'd take the V-belt off and give a wiggle to all the bearings that it turns..

Comment: My car has done 67 thousand miles